# MongoDB query failing

Tags: ruby, mongodb, sinatra, mongomapper

I'm trying to use MongoMapper in my Sinatra app for a simple auction site, but I'm having trouble running a simple query and getting any results.

```
before '/auction/:id' do
    connection = Mongo::MongoClient.new
    db = connection.db('auction')
    collection = db['auctions']

    @query = Plucky::Query.new(collection)
end

get '/auction/:id' do
    @auction = @query.where({:id => params["id"].to_i})
    "#{@auction.inspect}"
end
```

But I get no output with `@auction.inspect` in the browser. However, when I use the query `@auction = @query.all` I get all of the records within my database.

Params (when using url localhost/auction/3):

```
{"splat"=>[], "captures"=>["3"], "id"=>"3"}
```

`query.all` output:

```
[{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('529cbbee21f7f10dd4000005'), "id"=>2, "name"=>"jump", "price"=>1.42}, {"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('529cbbf821f7f10dd400000e'), "id"=>3, "name"=>"here", "price"=>93.34}]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MongoMapper (or more accurately, Plucky, the library that builds MongoMapper queries) casts a field called `id` to `_id` automatically for parity with ActiveRecord, so you can't use two different fields called `_id` and `id`. You'll see that if you look at the generated query in your logs.

In this case, you'd want to use a different field name.

Answer (score 0):

`.where` builds the association, but you'll need to call a method like `all` or `first` to perform the query and get results:

```
@auction = @query.where({:id => params["id"].to_i}).first
```